# Programmatically filtering logcat for my application. not working for me

Tags: android, logcat

In an android app I am trying to get my application log messages and saving them to file
I am using the code below. 
I am using a different TAG for each of my class and there are several of them.
doing logcat -d gives me all irrelevant messages..
putting my package name like

logcat -d myapp.com:I *:S

does not work the results are empty but if I do

logcat -d MYCLASS1TAG:I MYCLASS2TAG *:S

then it works, but I have many classes..

how can I just put my package name and get results ..??

```
try  {      
       Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

   String line;  

   while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
    {


 //       write to my file here

   }
  }  catch (IOException e)    {   }
```

Comment: I'm afraid you have to list all your tags. Or you filter that full log manually.

Comment: In eclipse when you see logcat there is an application column in there which shows your package name. That makes me believe it might be possible

Comment: I guess they are filtering the log manually. At least http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat only lists `tag:priority` and `*:priority`

Comment: Yes that's what I saw int he manual. Typing all tags is very inconvinient.. I have almost 20 TAGS ..

Comment: You could create some class that has a static array of tags for your other classes to use (or create a fancy registry thing) - use that list to build the string programatically. But well - that might be more work than just typing 20 tags :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it from the command line, but the ADT plugin for Eclipse lets you filter by application.

edit: I was curious, so I looked through the ADT source to figure out how ADT does it. The long and short of it is that it uses the `-v long` option to include the PID with each message, and it keeps a Map from a PID to an app name. The relevant source code files are in the package `com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatMessageParser` and `com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatPidToNameMapper`.

So, one workaround I can think of is to call up a shell (`adb shell`), figure out your PID using `ps`, and then pipe the output of adb logcat to grep:

```
adb logcat -v long | grep <your PID>
```

It will be a bit of a pain since your PID will change every time you run the app, but that's how you can do it in a pinch.

edit: I just noticed that the long format actually prints the PID on one line and the message on the next line, so you may need to use something like awk instead of grep. I'll test a few things out and post a followup.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Brian :)

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand it you are trying to run logcat on the device to grab and save to file. Unfortunately in the current command line the filterspec only supports the `tag:priority` format. You will need to run the output through your own line by line filter. You can probably automate this by figuring out your PID and then filtering lines based on that.