# How long android logs are stored?

Tags: android, android-logcat

Basically I want to create some functionality for my app so that I could write logs to file every X hours.

I want to know how long these logs are stored in the memory buffer or where ever they are stored on the phone? Is this buffer cleared on the phone reboot or after specific period of time?

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you're referring to the logs displayed by "logcat".

The logs are written to a circular buffer managed by a kernel driver.  They do not exist on disk.  There is no expiration date; older messages are simply removed to make room for newer messages as they arrive.  The size of the buffer is device-dependent.

If you want to write logs that will live for hours, you should create your own log file in the app-specific data area (perhaps [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29)).

This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798545/about-android-logcat-in-real-device/) may be of interest.